# Docker-compose-configuration for Vaultwarden+Traefik2

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I've generated this docker-compose config for Vaultwarden using Traefik. The container works, but I can't get to it via the https address.
My configuration docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"  
services:  
  vaultwarden:  
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest  
    container_name: vaultwarden  
    restart: always  
    environment:  
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug  
      - "SIGNUPS_ALLOWED=false"  
    labels:  
      - "traefik.enable=true"  
      - "traefik.http.routers.bw.rule=Host(`vaultwarden.xxxxx.it`)"  
      - "traefik.http.routers.vaultwarden.entrypoints=web"  
      - "traefik.http.routers.bw.tls.certresolver=myresolver"  
      - "traefik.http.services.bw.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"  
    volumes:  
      - ./data/:/data  
    expose:  
      - "8081"  
    ports:  
      - "81:80"  
networks:  
  default:  
    name: webproxy  
    external: true
```

I can reach the vaultwarden-page with http://localhost:81.
But I cannot reach the page with https://vaultwarden.xxxxx.it. I get the error "Bad gateway". Where is the error in the configuration? The traefik-proxy is configurated do redirect an external http-address always to https.
Can you help me?

Comment: What sort of diagnostics have you performed? Have you checked the Traefik console to see if the configuration looks correct?

Comment: Hello @rupi, I get counfused. Based your question you said that you can not access to the services using HTTPS. Your `docker-compose.yml` do not expose any configuration nor port binding into HTTPS / 443. Can you review your question or implement a correctness along your `.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to connect to vaultwarden with `http://localhost:81` the service within the container seems to listen on port `80` (given the port forwarding `81:80`).

But in in your traefik labels your pointing to the port `8081`. Probably there is nothing listening on this port within the container and you simply need to correct it to `"traefik.http.services.bw.loadbalancer.server.port=80"`.

When this works you can also drop the `ports` and `expose` properties from the service since you then don't need to directly expose any ports of the service but it can be accessed through traefik.